# Controls Origin Change

Tags: wpf

Does anyone know:

1. Why the origin in some controls is at Center of the Bounds,in some at TopRight corner and in some at TopRight - 10px?
2. How to change the origin of a Control in WPF?

Methods tried:

1. For getting origin of the Control in a Canvas:`myControl.TranslatePoint(new Point(0,0),null)`;
2. Tried:

`myControl.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.0,0.0);
 myControl.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5,0.5);
 myControl.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(1.0,1.0);`

Tried changing VerticalAlignment and HorizontalAlignment.
Nothing Happened.

As analysis,I tried putting a Red Line in MouseMove Event which has as start Point the Canvas Origin,and as End point:

`myLine.X2 = myControl.TranslatePoint(new Point(0,0),null).X;
myLine.Y2 = myControl.TranslatePoint(new Point(0,0),null).Y;`

This line points in SOME CONTROLS on the Center of control,and in some other controls at the Top-Right corner,But NEVER at Top-Left.

The Alignments of ALL Controls are set to Stretch/Stretch.

Answer (score 0):

Googling around,I found some interesting explainations of similar scenario,due to DPI changes/settings:I tried simply SWITCHING DPI to 120% from 100% and Back:

WPF now reports another WRONG positioning of controls on my Canvas,but ALL PROBLEMS in my questions,seems now have an explaination,not yet a solution.

How exactely can a wrong DPI set can influence ONLY HitTest,TranslateTransforms and Render process,without influencing Canvas.SetLeft/Right/Top/Bottom or Margin propery or ScaleTransform?

I read about DisableDpiAwarenessAttribute in assembly,but It seems not working…
What can be happened?